# How to show servlet results in jsp page?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I wrote a simple counter servlet application to show number of users who visit to a page. I want to show this result in jsp page. But how can I do it? following is my code...

```
public class ServerClass extends HttpServlet {
int counter = 0;
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
int local_count;
synchronized(this) {
local_count = ++counter;
}
out.println("Since loading, this servlet has been accessed " +
        local_count + " times.");
out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be implementing `doGet` (and `doPost` if you're making `POST` requests). Nothing calls `processRequest` unless it's called from one of the [normal servlet `doXxx` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

Expose the variable via a request attribute:

```
// Convention would name the variable localCount, not local_count.
request.setAttribute("count", local_count);
```

Forward to the JSP:

```
getServletContext()
    .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/showCount.jsp")
    .forward(request, response);
```

Use JSP EL (Expression Language) to display the attribute:

```
Since loading, this servlet has been accessed ${count} times.
```

If the local count variable doesn't appear, make sure your `web.xml` file is configured for the latest servlet revision.

Comment: thanks Dave.. but it shows null value for count variable. i checked web.xml. do not know what to do.. iam novel to servlet..

Comment: @Rosh Right now you're using `processRequest`, you should be using `doGet` for HTTP `GET` requests. If it's still showing `null` after implementing `doGet`, you'll need to post more details.